# How to create PDF file using Wordpress Rest API

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a PDF file using WP Rest API. I wrote this small code on `function.php`. But when I call the API from the postman, it shows - **Internal Server Error**.

Here is my code:

```php
add_action(
    'rest_api_init',
    function () {
        register_rest_route(
            'api',
            '/get_location',
            array(
                'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                'callback' => 'get_location',
            )
        );
    }
);

function get_location() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = array();
    
    require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;
    $options = new Options();

    $options->set( 'isRemoteEnabled', true );
    // Instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf( $options );
    $dompdf->loadHtml( 'hello world<br/>TEST' );
    $dompdf->setPaper( 'A4', 'landscape' );

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $now    = strtotime( 'now' );
    // file_put_contents($now.".pdf", $output);
    file_put_contents( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dompdf/' . $now . '.pdf', $output );

    return $results;
```

The above code show internal server error in postman

Comment: Did you look at your web server's error log? Did you enable WP_DEBUG_LOG? Please [edit] your question to tell use what you see in those places, so we can help you better.

Comment: Your code has a few mistakes but the main mistake I am guessing for the error is ** you are missing the closing bracket after ` return $results;` on function `get_location`** some other mistakes are you should call the `autoload.inc.php` at the top of the file, also use `use Dompdf\Dompdf;` and `use Dompdf\Options;` at the top of the file after loading `autoload.inc.php`, another reason for the error could be `get_location` is not a unique function name, make sure you prefix it and make it unique e.g. `vh_custom_get_pdf_location`